# jQuery $.fn not working with no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've seen this question asked before and googled but to no avail. I'm trying to learn how to create my own function in jQuery but it doesn't do what I'm asking and I'm not receiving any errors. Have I done something wrong here?

Here's the script

```
<script type='text/javscript'> 
    (function($){ 
        $.fn.selectMe = function(options){ 
            return this.each(function(){ 
               $(this).find('li').append("<input type='checkbox'>"); 
            }); 
        } 
    }(jQuery)); 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.Select').selectMe(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

For good measure, here's the HTML

```
<div class='Select'>
    <p>Cuisine Types (3/10)</p>
    <ul>
        <li>American</li>
        <li>Italian</li>
        <li>Chinese</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/22/

Comment: That's very odd. I didn't think to test it outside of my own environment. Thanks. I don't suppose anyone could think of any reason it wouldn't work? All my other jQuery works fine. I'm using localhost with xampp. Thanks again!

Comment: did you check your browser console?

Comment: Working fine for me too @b3tac0d3 you might having the problem with the other code  can you put down your environmental code here.? if possible you can put that would help further

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with the problem though. but I observed:

- `<script type = 'text/javscript'>` should be `<script type='text/javascript'>`
- `(function ($) {  }(jQuery));` should be: `(function($){ })(jQuery);`

This works great. Try this:

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.selectMe = function (options) {
  return this.each(function () {
   $(this).find('li').append("<input type = 'checkbox'>");
  });
 }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.Select').selectMe();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'Select'>
    <p>Cuisine Types (3/10)</p>
    <ul>
        <li>American</li>
        <li>Italian</li>
        <li>Chinese</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: _"(function ($) {  }(jQuery)); should be: (function($){ })(jQuery);"_ Returns identical results

Comment: he he he... because your answer is downvoted, you will downvote other's?

Comment: Missed the missing "a" :)

Comment: I didn't missed it. Marked it in the first line my solution.

Comment: And this way, this deserves to be selected as Correct Answer... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88532/discussion-between-guest271314-and-ashish-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Facepalm! I can't believe I wasted 2 hours on this and everyones time. I spelled javascript wrong and it threw off all the code but no errors. I'm sorry all but thank you for all the feedback!

Comment: I got this at very first place. Have I not mentioned this in my solution? **And still I got 3 downvotes?** I think I should review the user before answering them...

Comment: What is purpose of "downvote" where OP found own solution ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: same thing mention in previous answer why not accept as answer instread of adding new answer

Comment: Well the previous answer didn't point that out as my error. It was pointing at syntax. But to each his own if that's how everyone want's to see it.

Comment: Well, the first observation of mine was the same what you mentioned in your own answer.